# Optimize black box function with one of the output as constraint

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, extreme-value

I have used deep learning to obtain an objective function (or black box) which I need to optimize to get max output.

So the inputs are a1,b1,b2,...,b8 while outputs are x,y and z = x^2/y.

I need to get max z but at the same time, the value of a1 whereby z is max must also satisfy the condition that:

a1 value when z is max <= a1 value when y/1.5 is max

So how should I solve the problem? I have only tried hyperopt at the moment and I can use it to get max z using z = fn1(a1,b1,b2,...,b8) with some constraints of a1,b1-8.

Using the b1-8 values when z is max, I could use my deep learning trained y = fn2(a1,b1,b2,...,b8) to get max y. There is a special property in my case that y = fn2(a1) is a parabolic curve. Hence, since I now know the value of max y/1.5, I can decrease a1 by small increments until I get to a1 value when y/1.5 is max.

I then compare a1@max z and a1@max y/1.5. if a1 value when z is max <= a1 value when y/1.5 is max, end of the story. Else, I need to redo the whole process again, but this time I need to constraint my max a1 to a smaller value. This will be an iteration process.

So although it worked, I wonder if there's a better way to solve this problem?

I'm also wondering if there's a loophole in this mtd, such that I might not get the correct ans...

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you please explain what "a1@max z <= a1@max y/1.5" might mean?  The "@" has no conventional meaning.

Comment: Sorry, a1@max z = the value of a1  when z is maximum. hope that clarifies

Comment: It does, but I'm puzzled by your phrase "y/1.5 is max."  What's the point of the 1.5?  When some value $y$ is maximized, so is $y/\sigma$ for any positive number $\sigma$ like $\sigma=1.5.$

Comment: It's sort of a safety constraint. so although we can achieve max y, it's safer to operate at a1 when y = max y/1.5. so as a1 increases, y will increase until a max and then decrease. hence there is a requirement that optimized a1 must be smaller than a1 at max y and it is at around max y/1.5.